# How to property save the updated managed object that has one-to-many relationships with other entities?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

If I have three entities in my Core Data that all have one-to-many relationships with each other:

```swift
extension Progress {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Progress> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Progress>(entityName: "Progress")
    }

    @NSManaged public var goal: Goal
    @NSManaged public var metric: Set<Metric>

}

extension Metric {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Metric> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Metric>(entityName: "Metric")
    }
    
    @NSManaged public var value: NSDecimalNumber
    @NSManaged public var metricToGoal: Goal
    @NSManaged public var progress: Progress

}

extension Goal {

    @nonobjc public class func createFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Goal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Goal>(entityName: "Goal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var progress: Set<Progress>
    @NSManaged public var goalToMetric: Set<Metric>
}
```

And if fetched one of the entities and update it:

```swift
let metricRequest = Metric.createFetchRequest()
metricRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "value == %@", metric.value)
if let fetchedMetric = try? self.context.fetch(metricRequest) {
   // update Metric
}
```

Do I have to fetch the rest two entities as well and append the newly updated entity to them?

```swift
if let fetchedGoal = try? self.context.fetch(goalRequest) {
   fetchedGoal.goalToMetric.append(updatedMetric)
}

if let fetchedProgress = try? self.context.fetch(goalProgress) {
   fetchedProgress.metric.append(updatedMetric)
}
```

Or is Core Data smart enough that I just have to save context for the updated entity and it will take care of the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to fetch the rest two entities as well and append the newly updated entity to them?

No.
You can read more about how relational databases work, [here](http://www.upi.pr.it/docs/easfg/easvrfgp7.htm).

Single `Metric` object corresponds to the single record in the dedicated table in the CoreData-backed database.
If you update `value` of the `Metric` - no need to update relations.
In case of one-to-many relation, each `Metric` record in the database will store only the `ObjectID` of the `Goal` and `Progress`. Neither `Goal` nor `Progress` records will store any information about the metrics they relate to.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that even though Core Data uses SQLite internally, its API is very different from relational databases in some ways. For example that page describes the use of foreign keys to manage relationships. Core Data might do that internally but it's almost never a good idea to try and use foreign keys with Core Data.